# Adding the variable in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wants to add the jquery variable in the selector with the following code. Please help how do I do this? Actually class is dynamic here and its changing again and again when page is loaded.

```
$(document).on('click', '#jivochatclick', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var className = $('#jvlabelWrap jdiv:nth-child(1) > jdiv:nth-child(1)').attr('class');
  $("#jvlabelWrap '+className+'").click(); // Not able to add className variable after #jvlabelWrap
  });
```

HTML Part

```
<a class="cta-btn align-middle" href="#" id="jivochatclick">Enquire Now</a>
```

Comment: what is the actual issue you are having ? You forgot to add the problem statement. I do not get what you are trying to do ?

Comment: .... please all the relevant HTML to this code as well. and => you are not concatenating `++` the sting correctly.

Comment: I don't see the logic in your code... Why are you getting an element, getting its class, and then discarding the element to get the same element again by its class?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol actually class is dynamic and its changing again and again when page is loaded

Comment: Okay? But you already have the element when you do `$('#jvlabelWrap jdiv:nth-child(1) > jdiv:nth-child(1)')`, you don't need to get its class, discard the element, then look up the element again. That's just stupid. That's like finding someone, asking their name, then dismissing them back into the crowd so you can search the entire crowd for that person by their name when *you already have them there*.

Comment: `$("#jvlabelWrap .'+className+'").click()` - you're missing the `.` for the class name selector.  Also note that, as presented, `.attr("class")` *will* return multiple classes so you'd need to add `"."` to each of them - probably need `$("#jvlabelWrap .'+className.replace(" ", ".")+'").click()`

Comment: Why get the class from the a single item then select by class to select all with the same class?  Think that answers that question...  That's like finding someone, asking their name then calling into the crowd for all their family members.

Comment: Do this `var s = "#jvlabelWrap "+className;` and see if it's a valid selector.

Comment: Also notice that you're embedding a `'` inside the `"`  so should be `$("#jvlabelWrap ."+className)` otherwise your selector becomes `"#id 'class class'"` when it should be `"#id .class.class.class"`